# Online SDK / IDE for Open-Source Projects

Tags: sdk, open-source, ide, wiki

Is there any online, editable, code base that can also compile the code?

This is more of an "I wish" than a question, since I've tried to find one with no success. It seems to me that there are a number of open-source, very popular systems which could be integrated for a great benefit to the open-source community.

1. An online collaborative tool, basically a wiki. Needs to have some versioning.
2. An IDE/SDK type tool - at a minimum just a syntax checker and compiler

If these two are combined, you would have an open source project that anyone contribute to. The way I see it working is like this:

- Every wiki page is a single class
- To update a class you must pass a syntax check, including not breaking any other classes that depend on this class
- There are two kinds of users - administrators and contributors (who can be anonymous).

  - Administrators have to approve updates to classes before they can be included in a compile-able release. They also rate the changes that they "approve", which is a sort-of ranking system for the contributors. If security is a concern, you could say that every approved change is randomly assigned to another admin for approval, and if that person detects malicious code then the first approver is now suspect and may be removed from being an admin.
  - Contributors can download any approved release, and can optionally download a version that includes all of their own revisions that have not been approved yet. This is normally for their own testing, but maybe they just want to change a behavior, even if no one else likes that change.
- Any class (that meets certain requirements) can be marked as a "root" class, which means it can be compiled with its dependencies.

The advantages with this system seem huge to me!

- Participation with almost no effort. The work of joining an open-source project is normally at a minimum an hour or more. That is in addition to initially downloading and installing a compatible SDK tool.
- Learning about open-source with much reduced effort. I see many more people joining in with a friendly, wikipedia style site that they can just browse through as a way of learning the code base
- Better code base (refactoring) All those people who tweak wikipedia will be free to tweak source code too. Cleaner code will in turn be easier to read and maintain.
- Easy customization If I want to add a feature to my favorite open-source software, I can just make a change and download the compiled version. No need to
- This could be a build process for web servers. Plug this into updating a web-site, and it can replace your current build server. When a version is approved, it just deploys the update (presumably on a schedule so it is during low-usage hours)

I see a few down-sides, the same as those that already exist in wiki sites and open-source projects, somewhat amplified. But I think these all have somewhat standard

- Public/anonymous contributions could be bad or malicious
- Blocking "spam" contributions
- Bandwidth of downloads (all those executable files)
- CPU to compile all the versions

Does any such thing exists? If not, how feasible would it be for a team to put this together? Are there any other major problems that could kill this idea?

This idea just occurred to me one day, and I can't find it. I'm putting this "out there" partially to "establish prior art". This idea is free to be taken and used, just not free to be patented :p.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/)?

From their website:

> Cloud9 IDE is an online development environment for Javascript and Node.js applications as well as HTML, CSS, PHP, Java, Ruby and 23 other languages... Teams can collaborate on projects and run them within the browser. When you're finished, deploy it—and you're done!